# ggsave is not saving my scatterplot correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggsave

I am trying to save a scatterplot that looks nice in RStudio but is not working when I am saving it in a loop with `ggsave()` or `png()`. I tried changing the width and the height but it is not working

[saved from the plot in Rstudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2v9ao.png)

[saved with ggsave or png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg1H6.png)

```
for (i in traits) {
  scatter<- ggplot(datos, aes(x = TREATMENT, y = i, 
                   label = ifelse(TREATMENT %in% checks, TREATMENT, ""), size = 0.4)) +
    geom_text_repel(size = 2,
                    point.padding = 0.2, 
                    nudge_x = 0.05,
                    nudge_y = 0,
                    segment.curvature = 0, max.overlaps = Inf,
                    arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.015, "npc"))) +
    geom_point(aes(color = pop), size = 1, na.rm = T) + 
    theme_classic() + 
    scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Set1")
  
  png(file = paste0("images/01_scatterplot_raw", i, ".png"), width = 720, height = 720)
  print(scatter)
  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: Try saving with ggsave() instead

Comment: `png` has pixels as default width/height unit, whereas `ggsave` uses inch per default. Make sure to set values and units as desired.

Comment: Besides setting the same `width`, `height` and `units` you also have to use the same resolution. By default `ggsave` uses a resolution of `dpi=300` whereas `png` uses `res=72` if not set.

Comment: Thanks! I already tried with the same results...

ggsave(
  filename = paste0("images/01_scatterplot_raw",".png"),
  dpi = 300,
  units = "in",
  width = 8,
  height = 6
)

Comment: The difference between your two images here do not suggest the issue is with DPI, moreso that limits are being set differently. Can you post a sample of `datos` (perhaps `dput(head(datos[,c("TREATMENT", traits[1])],30))`) and update your two plots with that sampled data?

Comment: I tried, and it works with only 30 data... I tried setting the limits huge (1256x514 px) but still doesn´t work with ggsave all data in datos (735 obs)